# Does webkit have a css rendering switch?

Tags: css, webkit

i just want to the dom parser part.

Comment: do you want the engines source code? you may have a look at the chromium project: http://www.chromium.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check this Chrome extension out: [Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm).

With this you can turn off all CSS, highlight different elements (including custom) and all sorts of other fancy things!

Hope it helps you out :)